# Nginx Echo Subrequest not working

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, load-balancing, haproxy

I am new to Nginx.

My requirement is I need to make a service call but along with proxy passing that request, I need to make call to another service/servlet. For this I decided to use Echo module to use the echo_subrequest_async option.

However the subrequest is not working and even simple echo print is not working. Where does echo "hello" supposed to go? to the client side (my guess)

Below is my configuration (some notes):

1. Both the servers are java servers which are running on my local box
2. my os is mac osx version 10.9.5
   3, I compile nginx 1.6.2 from source and with modules pcre and http echo

```
nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
built by clang 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
configure arguments: --with-pcre=/Users/xxxx/project/pcre-8.35 --add-module=/Users/xxxx/project/echo-nginx-module-0.57 --with-cc-opt=-Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

nginx config I have used is as follows

```
http {

    server {
       listen 80;
       server_name localhost;

        # this will handle the initial request
        location /messaging-service {
            default_type "text/plain"; 
            echo "in the messaging service call";
            echo_flush;
            echo_subrequest_async GET '/mywebapp/second';
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8090/messaging-service/; 
        }

        # this is where the sub request should go,note its different service
        location /mywebapp/second {
            echo "Going to make another call on different server !!";
            echo_flush;
            proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/second/;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Something in your error log ?

Comment: Hi Xavier there are no errors in the error logs. I was able to see Nginx making call to http://localhost:8090/messaging-service/ however there is no logs for subrequest async.